# SumatraPDF automatically returns to Sublime Text 3

Tags: sublime-text, sumatrapdf, latextools

Just now I find myself involved in a somewhat funny problem in using the combination of Sublime Text 3 (ST3) and SumatraPDF.

I use LaTeXTools in ST3. Normally, when the source file is finished in compilation without any errors, the generated PDF file will prompt in SumatraPDF; however, my situation is more than that because there is an extra activity: **it *immediately* returns to the ST3 window (without a double-click to request inverse search)**.

Any one has encountered this problem? Or any one knows how to prevent the extra movement?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There's a LaTeXTools setting called `keep_focus` that you'll need to change to `false` to stop this from happening. You can access the settings by selecting **Preferences > Package Settings > LaTeXTools > Settings – User**.

Comment: Cool! So it is not a problem but just one of some updated default settings of LaTeXTools?

Comment: Something like that.