# Sumatra Inverse Search Open new Window in Sublime

Tags: sumatrapdf

when I perform an inverse search in Sumatra on a pdf (with the corresponding tex file open in SublimeText3) the program open a new window in Sublime instead showing it directly in the one already open.
The new window is of the form

> c:\Filepath

instead of

> C:\Filepath

It seems like Sumatra uses a lower case c instead of the common C.

This is the inverse search command line:

> "C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3\sublime_text.exe" "%f:%l"

Do you have any idea of why it has this strange behaviour?
Thanks

Answer (score 5):

Use any simple.TeX Ctrl+Shift+P (Build)

SumatraPDF should have fired up with the compiled PDF

Go To Settings > Advanced Options

and going down the entries check or change the following

ReuseInstance = true

ReloadModifiedDocuments = true

InverseSearchCmdLine = "C:\Program Files\Sublime Text 3\sublime_text.exe" "%f:%l"

EnableTeXEnhancements = true

UseTabs = true

In SumatraPDF Settings > Advanced options there are other settings for color of forward search highlight etc. I recommend you set HighlightPermanent = true

DONT FORGET TO CTRL+S (File Save)

Now a double click in the PDF should take you back to Sublime Text either in an included file or the main file. IF not, check the syntax of the InverseSearchCmdLine = matches YOUR location for sublime_text.exe

Be aware in some languages the path may be translated from a different localised one.

If you have a whatever.pdf, whatever.synctex(.gz) and whatever.tex file in the same folder then you can start by opening the PDF and a double click anywhere will open the tex editor with the cursor at the right file position even if the editor was not started first.

If the file keeps opening a fresh tex file then one or more of the following needs fixing
1) The path to sublime is incorrect
2) The synctex file is incorrect (check the synctex file time is the same as the PDF)
3) The editor is not set correctly so as to reopen the focused file.

There are several settings in Sublime LaTeX that can change behaviour 
for one affecting focus control see [SumatraPDF automatically returns to Sublime Text 3](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/331386/sumatrapdf-automatically-returns-to-sublime-text-3)

If you are still having problems with LaTeXTools you need to raise them at https://github.com/SublimeText/LaTeXTools