# Inverse search in Sumatra PDF opens new instance of TeXnicCenter

Tags: texniccenter, sumatrapdf

When using inverse search, `Sumatra PDF` opens a new instance of TeXnicCenter. 
Sumatra inverse search command is:

```
"C:\Program Files\TeXnicCenter\TeXnicCenter.exe" /ddecmd "[goto('%f', '%l')]"
```

According to some advices I tried to change Sumatra advanced settings

[Sumatra Inverse Search Open new Window in Sublime](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/460971/sumatra-inverse-search-open-new-window-in-sublime)

> ReuseInstance = true

TeXnicCenter settings, define output profiles is:

> Latex Tab

```
C:\Program Files\MiKTeX 2.9\miktex\bin\x64\pdflatex.exe

-synctex=-1 -interaction=nonstopmode "%Wm"
```

Viewer tab:

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\SumatraPDF\SumatraPDF.exe -inverse-search -reuse-instance"\"C:\Program Files\TeXnicCenter\TeXnicCenter.exe\" /ddecmd \"[goto('%f','%l')]\""
```

Project's output

```
[Open("%bm.pdf",0,1,1)]
```

Forward search:

```
[ForwardSearch("%bm.pdf","%Wc",%l,0,0,1)]
```

[image]

[image]

I'm using project in TexnicCenter. Main file includes other `.tex` files. I think this could be the issue. Many thanks for advices!

Comment: Does this answer your question? [The SumatraPDF Inverse-Search for any arbitrary Editor](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/125546/the-sumatrapdf-inverse-search-for-any-arbitrary-editor)